# Slow tab completion for paths in`make' arguments

Tags: command-line, make, tab-completion

When I'm specifying an argument for `make` like `PREFIX_PATH=/some/path/to/prefix/` I sometimes experience very slow completion for my directories (a few seconds). It's annoying when I've got several variables to specify.

To get around the problem I've been typing out the variables first to get regular completion speed, then hitting <kbd>Home</kbd> to insert `make` at the start of my command line. What is happening and how can I fix it?

Comment: NFS or Samba filesystem? Or maybe it's bash-completion? Try disabling it if that's used.

Comment: It's and NFS filesystem. The problem is really noticeable when the server and network are loaded. What I don't understand is why the completion is bad when it's completing for a `make` arg, but is fine when completing for a shell variable.

Comment: I'm also not sure how how to disable what you're talking about.

Comment: You need to address a comment poster like this: @maxelost or they might never see the reply.

Comment: @ajwood: if you use bash-completion (it's a package addition to bash), then try to figure out how to disable it (e.g. look at /usr/share/doc/bash-completion/README.gz), and see if it helps.

Comment: @maxelost: Disabling bash-completion _does_ fix my problem, however creates a new problem -- I don't have bash completion! Is there any other solution?